# The arrows in my bootstrap carousel code are not aligning properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, carousel

I have tried this code from a site:

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>



  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="DESIGNS/arcs.jpg" alt="arc" class="img-responsive"/>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="DESIGNS/carmelas.jpg" alt="carmela" class="img-responsive"/>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And the side buttons are not overlapping with the pictures. Instead, the side arrows are staying on the right side only.

Help. What should I do or change?

Comment: Can you show me the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine

See this

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/UPGwqnckq1)

Comment: I realized it's working fine when I tried publishing it as an HTML file. It won't work properly in ASP.NET